# What happen if you press alt ctr del while doing blockinput()

Tags: c#, .net, mouseevent, mouse, mouseclick-event

I used blockinput() and it blocked the mouse very well. But when I used <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> it released the mouse  again.

What happened exactly?

Any ideas on how to block  mouse right away when user clicks it?

Comment: This is not specific to C# or .NET, but to OS. (which you didn't specify)

Answer (score 1):

I am not hundred percent sure, but I think Ctrl-Alt-Delete overrides anything else. Your program is likely to run in user space and thus with restrictions aplied. Generally it would not be desirable to allow a user space application to block all input, for you could take control over the whole computer. Therefor a user will always be allowed to override your aplications BlockInput with CAD.